# How to customize the Combobox dropdown list?

Tags: macos, combobox, macos-carbon

I have created a Combo box using HIComboBoxCreate(). When I have a long string in the dropdown list, it goes beyond the screen and the starting of the string is not visible. I want the string to be truncated with ellipsis in such a case. I have looked into the ComboBox attributes but couldn't find any that I can use to set this. I'm ready to write some extra code to do this, but I'm not sure if it possible. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `HIViewSetTextTruncation` function.